# How to verify that a URL parameter has not been tampered with?

Tags: java, checksum

Imagine I have a some web page implemented in Java, which is available at `http://mycompany.com/page1.xhtml?trafficSource=someTrafficSourceIdentifier&checkSum=...`.

I want to keep track of how many page visits are generated by different traffic sources (such as different advertising campaigns). For this purpose, I have the `trafficSource` parameter. The set of traffic source IDs is limited to 5 possible values (e. g. Google organic, Google AdWords, YouTube, Facebook, Twitter).

Imagine, I want to make sure that `trafficSource` has not been tampered with (nobody has placed there a different value). For this purpose, I introduce the `checkSum` parameter.

What is the easiest way to create a check sum for a string X (`checkSum = f(X)`), such that different input strings are converted to different check sums?

The purpose of this measure is a **basic** check of my parameters.

I tried to use the following, but it produces a byte array with non-alphanumeric characters, which I can't put into the URL.

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class CheckSumGenerator {
    public String calculateCheckSum(final String aInput) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");

        final byte[] checkSumBytes = md.digest(aInput.getBytes());

        final String result = new String(checkSumBytes);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the problem is placing a value other than one of those 5, it'd be faster to just do string comparison. If the problem is people faking which site they came from, the problem is impossible because they can just copy the checkSum from whatever site they're impersonating.

Comment: Can't I create a key (which only I know), then create checksums for each of the valid strings with that key? Then, when someone changes the `trafficSource` parameter, he or she won't be able to generate the right `checkSum` because only I have the key. Are there easy ways to do that?

Comment: If you can convince Google, Facebook, and Twitter to create special PHP to recalculate your link to include a hash of the current time and a shared secret each time it's about to be served to a user, sure.

Comment: you really CAN'T guarantee this, as long as it's passed in as plain text.  At best, you can pass the value along as say an md5 hash or something (this will make recreating a value difficult), and look for matching values, if none found, presume it to be an "organic" source.  Or the suggested answer of using the http request header is probably a better (and more tamper proof, though still not 100 percent flawless) way of doing it.

Comment: Can't you just store the traffic source to your HTTP session the first time someone gets redirected to your site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the referrer on your server side from the http request header, which is not visible to the user. This could identify visitors coming from youtube or facebook.

To solve your problem of converting the hash to a alphanumeric string, you could convert the resulting bytes to hex code.

```
final String result = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(checkSumBytes);
```

Comment: Even this has the potential to be tampered with, but it's still much better than passing plain string values over.